# Blank screen while installing Software Update -- htc one x

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, ota-update

I was on 4.0.4. I saw a software update notification, and I clicked it. The update was about 35mb. It downloaded successfully. But when I selected to install it, it first took more than 30 minutes. Now, there is nothing, just a black screen. Not sure even if the phone is ON or OFF.

**P.S.** While doing all this, my battery was very low. So, I had the phone connected with my laptop to give it power. Now I can see only the black screen (as if phone is switched off) and the orange light near the speaker is blinking that usually blinks to indicate charging.

Comment: This may sound saucy now: But you never should start any update without having charged your device to at least 90%. In most cases, you will still end up with 80% or even more -- but in several cases it literally saves you headaches...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned my phone was connected to the laptop. That was causing the problem. On my laptop MobileGo (PC suit for Android) services were running. When MobileGo detected the device it tried to connect with it. Which was actually interrupting the installation process.

From my task manager I stopped the MobilGo services and the installation went through.